# Impact of precedence of bit manipulation operator on output

Tags: c++, c, bit

I am running simple programe in visual studio 2008. which is giving 2 results as below.
Please help me knowing why in first case it is giving result =1024
case 1:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i =4;
    k = i<<3 + i<<1;
    cout<<"Result "<<k;

    return 0;
}
```

output is 1024

```
case2:
    int j=0;
    j=i<<3;
    int n = i<<1;
    k = j+ n;
    cout<<"Result "<<k;
```

Output is 40

Comment: Give us enough code to reproduce your results. Also, what did you expect and why did you expect it?

Comment: what do mean by  `k = i<<3 + i<<1;`

Comment: @ShahrairNazimReal that is someone who *thinks* they are really smart trying to multiply by 10. The people who *are* really smart turn on the optimizer.

Comment: This is what the compiler had to say about your code: *" warning: operator '<<' has lower precedence than '+'; '+' will be evaluated first"*. You should enable warnings `-Wall` and fix the warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about the operator precedences:

```
i = 4;
k = i << 3 + i << 1;
// is the same expression as: 
k = (4 << (3 + 4)) << 1;
```

so `4 << (3+4) = 512`  and  `512 << 1 = 1024`

Comment: Thank you so much KIIV :) it was because of operator precedence